# How should asynchrony be handled in Cloud Code of Parse.com?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, parse-platform

I searched desperately for the answer to this question and arrived at this answer the hard way. Hopefully others will be saved the lost time I suffered. Perhaps someone will answer with improvements or a better pattern.

**EDIT:** *An earlier set of code I entered here has been replaced.*

In this method you can see how multiple calls to async operations can be made without callback nesting. it also shows how to put async code into smaller callable functions. The method also works to call async functions multiple levels deep. At each level, multiple async actions can be strung together to satisfy it's intent. Errors can be passed up the line and can bubble through sequences of .thens.

The log output should help one understand what is really going on.

Two things that would have really helped me as a parse and JS beginner: 1) Parse JS operations appear to be asynchronous when they return a promise and not otherwise, one exception is query.get(). 2) be very careful with the syntax of the .then call. 3) thrown errors will not be caught by the .then error function. To cause a an error use "return Parse.Promise.error()". 4) To understand promises, watch the screencasts from Mike Taulty, easily googled, thank you Mike.

This code has been tested on Parse.com.

```
function test0()
{
    console.log("test0.entry");
    var promise0 = test1("T", "col", "test1call1");

    var promise1 = promise0.then(function(ex) {
        console.log("test0.0.success - " + ex);
        return test1("T", "emailAddress", "test1call2");
    });
    var promise2 = promise1.then(function(ex) {
        console.log("test0.1.success - " + ex);
        return test2(1);
    });
    promise2.then(function(msg) {
        console.log("test0.2.success - " + msg);
        return;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("test0.2.error " + error.message);
        return;
    });
    console.log("test0.exit");
}

function test1(clss, col, val) 
// use as a method on a save request
// returns true if the column value already exists
{
    console.log("[" + val + "]" + "test1.entry");
    var c = Parse.Object.extend(clss);
    var query = new Parse.Query(c);

    query.equalTo(col, val);
    var promise1 = query.count();
    var promise2 = promise1.then(function(count) {
        console.log("[" + val + "]" + "test1.sub.success - " + count);
        if (col == "reject") {    
            var err = new Parse.Error(10001, "new test error");
            console.log("[" + val + "]" + "test1.sub.success - return test error");
            return Parse.Promise.error(new Parse.Error(10001, "test error (10001)"));
        } 
        return(count>0);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("[" + val + "]" + "test1.sub.error " + error.get("message"));
        return(false);
    });
    console.log("[" + val + "]" + "test1.return");
    return promise2;
};

function test2(n) 
// use as a method on a save request
// returns true if the column value already exists
{
    console.log("test2.entry");
    var c = Parse.Object.extend("T");
    var query = new Parse.Query(c);

    query.equalTo("col", "val");
    var promise1 = query.count();
    var promise2 = promise1.then(function(count) {
        console.log("test2.promise1.success - " + count);
        if (n==1) {
            return test1("T", "reject", "test2call1e");
        } else {
            return test1("T", "col", "test2call1");
        }
    });

    var promise3 = promise2.then(function(count) {
        console.log("test2.promise1.success - " + count);
        if (n==2) {
            return test1("T", "reject", "test2call2e");
        } else {
            return test1("T", "col", "test2call2");
        }
    });

    var promise4 = promise3.then(function() {
        console.log("test2.promise3.success - " + count);
        return "test2 completed";
    }, function(error) {
        // Catch some errors here and repair them
        console.log("test2.promise3.error - " + error.message);
        return Parse.Promise.as("test2 completed - error repaired");
    });

    console.log("test2.exit");
    return promise4;
};
```

It produced this output.

```
I2013-03-30T01:58:19.983Z] test0.entry
I2013-03-30T01:58:19.983Z] [test1call1]test1.entry
I2013-03-30T01:58:19.984Z] [test1call1]test1.return
I2013-03-30T01:58:19.984Z] test0.exit
I2013-03-30T01:58:20.085Z] [test1call1]test1.sub.success - 0
I2013-03-30T01:58:20.085Z] test0.0.success - false
I2013-03-30T01:58:20.085Z] [test1call2]test1.entry
I2013-03-30T01:58:20.085Z] [test1call2]test1.return
I2013-03-30T01:58:20.186Z] [test1call2]test1.sub.success - 0
I2013-03-30T01:58:20.186Z] test0.1.success - false
I2013-03-30T01:58:20.186Z] test2.entry
I2013-03-30T01:58:20.187Z] test2.exit
I2013-03-30T01:58:20.338Z] test2.promise1.success - 0
I2013-03-30T01:58:20.338Z] [test2call1e]test1.entry
I2013-03-30T01:58:20.338Z] [test2call1e]test1.return
I2013-03-30T01:58:20.439Z] [test2call1e]test1.sub.success - 0
I2013-03-30T01:58:20.439Z] [test2call1e]test1.sub.success - return test error
I2013-03-30T01:58:20.439Z] test2.promise3.error - test error (10001)
I2013-03-30T01:58:20.439Z] test0.2.success - test2 completed - error repaired
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your answer as an answer (you can accept your own answer after a cooling down period), and reword your question as a question.

Answer (score 1):

Working with Promises on Parse can get harder if you chain together many functions which are all inline. What I do instead is define each action as a function and then chain them together and finish them off with the final block with `handleSuccess` and `handleError`. That way each function is self contained and easy to understand while the chained sequence is organized and easy to update.

Both the `fetchThing` and `updateThing` functions return a Promise which include the `thing` instance. The fetched value is passed to the update function which is then passed to the next function in the chained sequence.

```
var fetchThing = function(objectId) {
    // set up a query with objectId
    return query.find();
};

var updateThing = function(thing) {
    // set properties on thing
    return thing.save();
}

var handleSuccess = function(result) {
    response.success(result);
};

var handleError = function(error) {
    response.error(error);
};

var objectId = 'asdfad';

fetchThing(objectId).then(function(thing) {
    return updateThing(thing);
}).then(handleSuccess, handleError);
```

I created a full example that I shared on GitHub which uses this style of programming with Cloud Code and Promises.

https://github.com/brennanMKE/PostThings/blob/master/Parse/PostThings/cloud/main.js